# NestJS authentication: how to globally pass UserId to CRUD endpoints?

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I've followed the [NestJS Authentication Guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication) and everything is working as expected:

A global JWT guard:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        // ...
        BoardsModule,
        // ...
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [
        // ...
        {
            provide: 'APP_GUARD',
            useClass: JwtAuthGuard,
        },
    ],
})
```

A controller:

```js
export class BoardsController {
  // ...
  @Get()
  findAll(@Req() req: any) {
     const userId = req.user.userId;
     return this.boardsService.findAll(userId);
  }
  // ...
}
```

A service that uses [prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) to fetch the boards for an authenticated user:

```js
export class BoardsService {
    // ...
    findAll(userId: string) {
        return prisma.board.findMany({
            where: {
                userId,
            },
        });
    }
   // ...
}
```

As most of my endpoints are user scoped I wonder how can one avoid passing the userId in CRUD endpoint again and again?

```js
   // ...
   const userId = req.user.userId;
        return this.boardsService.findAll(userId);
   }
   // ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure what type of solution you envision, but it's unlikely that there can be a global way of "getting" the user because the user is passed in the request when retrieved from the JWT so it always has to be extracted from the request.

Comment: @LiamClarkGutiérrez It seems I was looking for something in the lines of this: [@casl/prisma](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@casl/prisma). A way to split the concern of authorization away from the controller/selector coupling. IMHO, this split gives the architecture more dynamism, especially when the ability to share a resource is introduced => allowing a non-owner access to user-data.

Comment: Definetly a great approach, I haven't tried it but I've heard good things, all the best.