# Authentication for nestJs on cloudfunction

Tags: google-cloud-functions, nestjs

We are creating an integration between https://retreaver.com/integrations and a nestjs server running on a cloud function.

What methodology is best suited for nestjs integrations authentication?

What methodology is best suited for nestjs on cloud functions authentication?

I am assuming to just use a token authentication or something simple. but I am not sure at all! ( I have no idea where to look for this authentication piece, I looked at multiple youtube videos but I have not come across anything good )

I am following the following tutorial for learning nestJs:: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mgr5_r70OJQ

I looked around for similar questions but I didn't see anything close to what I was looking for. the only related question is the one below but there is no answer at the moment::
[NestJS authentication: how to globally pass UserId to CRUD endpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72515194/nestjs-authentication-how-to-globally-pass-userid-to-crud-endpoints)

example of nestjs on cloud function :: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmfDlUAokYc

Any advise or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways an app can authenticate its users and restrict access to only authorized users.To learn more about the various methods to authenticate users, see the [Authentication concepts](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/authenticate-users#authentication_concepts) section.

In order to integrate a NestJS app to serverless cloud functions, you may create a wrapper Express function and pass it to functions-framework, check the [thread](https://itnext.io/a-perfect-match-nestjs-cloud-functions-2nd-gen-nx-workspace-f13fb044e9a4) for details on the same.There is also a good example describing [the setup for the nest.js and cloud functions](https://fireship.io/snippets/setup-nestjs-on-cloud-functions/).
I would also recommend to check the below for more information:

- [Developing a secure api with nestjs adding authorization](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-a-secure-api-with-nestjs-adding-authorization/)
- [How to create a nestjs app with authentication](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-create-a-nestjs-app-with-authentication-c0ae845ff6ac)